# Spring JPA - How JSON should be formatted and how to call with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I've created a service with this specification:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "initCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Long> create(@RequestBody CustomerForm customerForm) {
```

The element `CustomerForm` have this structure (**i omit every getter/setter method**):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
    public static class CustomerForm {
        private String name;
        private String hostname;
        private List<ProbeMonitor> monitors;
@XmlElement(name = "monitor")
        public List<ProbeMonitor> getMonitors() {
            return monitors;
        }
}
```

The class `ProbeMonitor` is an `@Entity` with an `@EmbeddedId` (because this classe have more than one field in the primary key).

```
public class ProbeMonitor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ProbeMonitorId id;
    private Integer active;
    private Date inserted;
    private Date updated;

    @EmbeddedId
    public ProbeMonitorId getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And finally, `ProbeMonitorId`:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProbeMonitorId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String customer;
    private String name;
    private String type;
}
```

Now i should make a request to this service (using RestTemplate), but first i'm trying to use a simple REST client where i send JSON (to check that all works).

I'm sending JSON in this format, but i get "**Unrecognized field "id"**"

```
{
    "name": "test_name", 
    "hostname": "test_hosT", 
    "monitors": [
        {       "id": {"customer": "custom"},
            "active": "1"
         }
    ]
}
```

I've tried to remove the "id" fields in JSON request and WebService will be invoked correctly.

How "monitors" should be formatted?

And... (this is the second question) how i should create the RestTemplate to call this?

Comment: To ignore the id field, you should annotate your entity with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

Comment: I havent to ignore this property, i should send a list of monitor, each of this have "customer, name and type" property-

Answer (score 0):

I think to have found the problems:

1 - `private ProbeMonitorId id;` was not declared in JSON scope:

```
 @EmbeddedId
    **@XmlElement**
    @**JsonProperty**
    public ProbeMonitorId getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

2 - Inserted and updated was not declared to be ignored

```
@Basic
    @Column(name = "Dt_Insert")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Date getInserted() {
        return inserted;
    }
```

3 - Correct JSON sent:

```
{
    "name": "test_name", 
    "hostname": "test_hosT", 
    "monitors": [{
            "id": {"customer": "cst", "name": "aname", "type": "atype"},
                        "active": "1"
         }
    ]
```